# react-router V4 navigation issue

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have the below router settings for my application. In App.js below code are present.

```
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
  </Switch>
```

Under About component I have another sub division so i kept the routing separately for component which are coming under "About". In About(/about) component

```
class About extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>From AboutUs page</h3>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutIndex}/>
        <Route path='/about/details' component={Aboutdetails}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

When i click the 'AboutDetails" link it routing to the address "/about/details". Then when i try to click home page link as "/" or "/home" component or "/signin" component. It take me the address as "/about/" or "/about/home" or "/about/signin". In the address bar it is not loading the proper routing url insteadof that it always prefix "/about" component. This issue only when i click the component which are inside about components. But not for the "/about" component. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Find the below header code where the link are declared.

```
<Nav>
            <LinkContainer to="/home" activeClassName="active">
              <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/about" activeClassName="active">
              <NavItem eventKey={2}>About</NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/signin" activeClassName="active">
              <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <LinkContainer to="/home" activeClassName="active">
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Home</MenuItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to="/about" activeClassName="active">
                  <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>AboutUs action</MenuItem>
                </LinkContainer>
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem divider />
                <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
              </NavDropdown>
            </LinkContainer>
          </Nav>
```

Comment: Can you show your link code?

Comment: @SLee - I have updated the link code from header.jsx